# Stuck with creating if statement from string input

Tags: java, jframe, joptionpane

I am trying to learn Java and want it so you input your name, and if name input matches your name it will print Hello [your name], I am doing this using an if statement and make if so if the input is equal to a string equal to my name it will print hello plus the input. However it doesn't... the else statement is what confuses me because I got it to print the two value to see if they where equal and they both where... help would be appreciated thanks.

```
package AgeTester;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HelpSystem {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  String inp = "Jono";
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input Dialogue");

  String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What is your name?");

  if (inp == name) {
   System.out.printf("Hello", name);
  } else {
   System.out.println(inp + name);
  }
  System.exit(0);
 }
}
```

Comment: Use `inp.equals(name)` in `if` condition, and `inp.equalsIgnoreCase(name)` to ignore case of letters.

Comment: There is another error: inside if block, the `System.out.println` takes only one argument. Use `+` (or `StringBuilder`) for string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare two strings you should use the .equals(String) method

```
 if (inp.equals(name)) {
```

remember: `==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `equals()` method, it's what we use to comapre strings in Java not `==`.

```
if (inp.equals(name)) {
   System.out.printf("Hello", name);
  } else {
   System.out.println(inp + name);
  }
```